# How to make Filter get the result of LocaleChangeInterceptor on same request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a filter where I set an attribute to be displayed on JSP.

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    @Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,
    IOException
    {
      Locale currentLocale = localeResolver.resolveLocale( request );
      request.removeAttribute( KEY_BUYSIDE_NAME );
      if (Locale.ENGLISH.equals( currentLocale ))
      {
          request.setAttribute( "companyName", company.getName() );
      }
      else
      {
          request.setAttribute( "companyName", company.getLocalName() );
      }
    }
}
```

But it seems on same request, the filter is called before the LocaleChangeInterceptor.  Because the language I get is always late.  For example, when I set language to English from Japanese, I get Japanese. When I click later to Japanese, I get English.  It is always late for my case.

Answer (score 0):

To those who ran to same problem, I found workaround. I implemented:

```
private Locale getCurrentLocal( HttpServletRequest request )
{
    String localeParameter = request.getParameter( "lang" );
    if (!StringUtil.isEmpty( localeParameter ))
    {
        return org.springframework.util.StringUtils.parseLocaleString( localeParameter );
    }
    else
    {
        return localeResolver.resolveLocale( request );
    }
}
```

I copied the code from LocaleChangeInterceptor

Comment: Which I would say is hardly a solution but a hack, now if your parameter changes you need to hack your code and you basically duplicated things. The problem is that you are setting the value to early, you should be setting it after the request has been processed (assuming it is going to be used in the view for rendering) or instead of a filter use an interceptor and make sure it executes after the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`.